# How do I hide an object from the camera but keep the shadow in Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I can do it in Cycles but I don't know how to do it in Blender Internal. I'm using Blender 2.79 btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there seems to be this 'Cast Only' in the object's material settings, which seems to do the trick:

[image]

But why use internal, I just wonder...

Comment: Thank you very much. I use an old laptop.  And the rendering in the blender internal runs quickly on my laptop.